# Problema url al usar react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, react-hook-form

Tengo un proyecto en NextJs y estoy haciendo un formulario de alta de un empleado. Estoy usando `react-hook-form` y `axios`.

Mi archivo `page.tsx`:

```javascript
'use client'

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

import { createEmployee } from '@/services/employees'

function NewEmployee() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors, isSubmitting }
  } = useForm()

const onSubmit = async (employee) => {
    await createEmployee(employee)
  }

return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} className='space-y-8'>
...................
    </form>
  )
}

export default NewEmployee
```

Y mi servicio para crear el empleado es el siguiente:

```javascript
import axios from 'axios'

const { API_URL } = process.env

export const createEmployee = async (employee: Employee) => {
  console.log(`la url es: ${API_URL}/employees`)
  try {
    await axios.post(`${API_URL}/employees`, employee)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error)
    throw error
  }
}
```

`API_URL=http://localhost:3001/local` --> ese es la url de mi api y mi aplicacion de front corre en el puerto 3000.

El resultado del log de mi funcion es --> la url es: undefined/employees

No me esta tomando esa variable de entorno. En más, la consulta la esta haciendo aquí --> `http://localhost:3000/employees/undefined/employees`

¿Cuál puede ser el problema o error?

Comment: ¿Que versión de NextJS estas usando?

Comment: La versión 14 . Recién leyendo un poco más, agregue al servicio “use server” y me soluciono el problema jeje tengo q leer un poco más sobre esos temas de next 

Comment: Puedes contestar a tu propia pregunta, esto ayuda a mantener el sitio documentado, saludos

Answer (score 0):

La versión 14 de NextJS. Recién leyendo un poco más, agregue al servicio “use server” y me soluciono el problema